# What is the correct way to format a REST URL that sets object relationships?

Tags: rest

I was reading a REST web service tutorial here:

[www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069?pgno=3](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069?pgno=3)

It in, the example is a "Club" has "Person"s as members.

The suggested URL format for reading and updating a person is:

```
http://MyService/Persons/{PersonID}
```

The suggested URL format for reading and updating a club is:

```
http://MyService/Clubs/{ClubID}
```

My question is, what is the appropriate RESTful URL format for doing things like making a person a member of a club, or removing a person from a club?

For example, I'm imagining something like this ...

```
http://MyService/AddMemberToClub?clubid=1&personid=2
```

... but that doesn't seem to conform to the RESTful standard format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are responsibilities from the club itself not the person. This means that the person should have nothing to do with the resource you are trying to update, this being the club, not the person, as the person should not change its nature by adding it to a club (even though he might have a foreign key to the club).

So the best approach would be

```
/myService/clubs/{ClubId}/person/{PersonId}
```

This same url with a delete method should delete this person from the club and with put method should add the new person to the club.